# replacing jquery $.map with _.plunk

Tags: jquery, lodash

I want to use `lodash` in my code.

My Code :

```
$scope.annotations = $scope.dashboard.annotations.list;

  var isCheckedCriticalEvent = $.map($scope.annotations, function(obj) {
    if(obj.name === 'Critical') {
      return true;
    }
  });
  var isCheckedCritical = isCheckedCriticalEvent[0];
  var isCheckedMinorEvent = $.map($scope.annotations, function(obj) {
    if(obj.name === 'Minor') {
      return true;
    }
  });
  var isCheckedMinor = isCheckedMinorEvent[0];
  var isCheckedMajorEvent = $.map($scope.annotations, function(obj) {
    if(obj.name === 'Major') {
      return true;
    }
  });
  var isCheckedMajor = isCheckedMajorEvent[0];
  var isCheckedWarningEvent = $.map($scope.annotations, function(obj) {
    if(obj.name === 'Warning') {
      return true;
    }
  });
  var isCheckedWarning = isCheckedWarningEvent[0];
  $scope.annotation = {
    critical : isCheckedCritical,
    warning : isCheckedWarning,
    minor : isCheckedMinor,
    major : isCheckedMajor
  };
```

I am matching the object and then returning true.
What to replace in place of `$.map` I tried `_.map` and `_.filter` not getting exact result. `_.plunk` is also there but it is returning the array values. How can I use that.

Answer (score 0):

Something in the lines of

```
var First = 0;
var myFun = function(obj, text){ return obj.name === text; }
var isCheckedCriticalEvent = _.filter($scope.annotations, myfun(obj,'Critical'))[First];
```

however this would throw an error if filter return 0 elements if i'm not mistaken. It is better to check if returned array has length > 0.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this..

Is it correct ?

My Code :

```
$scope.annotations = $scope.dashboard.annotations.list;
      var isCheckedCritical = false;
      var isCheckedMinor = false;
      var isCheckedMajor = false;
      var isCheckedWarning = false;
      _.map($scope.annotations, function(obj) {
        if(obj.name === 'Warning') {
          isCheckedWarning = true;
        }
        if(obj.name === 'Major') {
          isCheckedMajor = true;
        }
        if(obj.name === 'Minor') {
          isCheckedMinor = true;
        }
        if(obj.name === 'Critical') {
          isCheckedCritical = true;
        }
      });
      $scope.annotation = {
        critical : isCheckedCritical,
        warning : isCheckedWarning,
        minor : isCheckedMinor,
        major : isCheckedMajor
      };
```

This is working fine.. Just want to know logic wise its correct or not.